# Shop Now Button & Add to Cart not working

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I got this message on the chrome dev. console. i need help

[Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
g.doXHR @ less-1.3.3.min.js:13